MS Access 2016 - Yes/No field
I have a simple form (Form1)which opens behind a command button. I would like to set the command to a macro but I cannot get it to work so I need some help with VBA - Form Load.
So basically I want to open Form1 but only show those records where the "Closed" Yes/No data type field is No. I know it should be something very simple..........any help appreciated
Macro
WHERE ISNULL(Forms!form1![Closed])

Yes/No field type is never Null. Must be either True or False (-1 or 0). WHERE [Closed] = False.

DoCmd.OpenForm has a WhereCondition parameter that will limit which records the form will show after it is opened.
Private Sub Command0_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenForm form1, acFormDS, , "Closed=No"
End Sub

From the documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.openform
Sub OpenForm(FormName,
             [View As AcFormView = acNormal], 
             [FilterName], 
             [WhereCondition], 
             [DataMode As AcFormOpenDataMode = acFormPropertySettings], 
             [WindowMode As AcWindowMode = acWindowNormal], 
             [OpenArgs])

Or create a macro that performs this form open and specify this macro in the buttons On Click event.
see How to handle the click function in Access form

Thanks a million - sorted!
